# Ubuntu doesn't work after installed in win8

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, windows-8

I got a new laptop with pre-install window8. I want to keep window8 and also to install ubuntu 12.04, 64Bit. I tried to boot from USB and install ubuntu like I did in win7, it went well but at the end, there was a warining said no grub. Then I  use easyBCD to add ubuntu into boot entry.it was success. But when i tried again to log in ubuntu ,it still didn't work.
what should I do?pls help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to boot into a live CD/USB and install & run [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_%3a_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu).